Changing the colors for Git PowerShell
ALL,
This is the content of my C:\Program Data\Git\config:
[core]
    symlinks = false
    autocrlf = true
    fscache = true
[color]
    diff = auto
    status = auto
    branch = auto
    interactive = true
[help]
    format = html
[rebase]
    autosquash = true


What do I change in order to see the actual diff?
Right now I am forced to copy that text and paste it into the Notepad...
I'd like the removal to be displayed in Red Bold.
TIA!!
On kind of related note - is there a documentation about what are the parameters name that can be changed? I need to add another things to configuration...
EDIT:
I just did a global search for gitconfig. Turns out I have many files with that name. One is in C:\Users\Igor, whose content was
[filter "lfs"]
    clean = git-lfs clean -- %f
    smudge = git-lfs smudge -- %f
    process = git-lfs filter-process
    required = true
[user]
    name = oneeyeman1
    email = ikorot01@gmail.com
[gui]
    recentrepo = C:/Users/Igor/OneDrive/Documents/dbhandler_app
[color]
#   ui = auto
    ui = true
[color "status"]
    changed = red bold
    untracked = red bold
    added = green
[color "diff"]
    meta = black
    old = red
    new = green

Changing "color "diff" -> old" to be "red bold" fixes the issue.
It would be nice to know what the first file for.
And all available options I can use to change the palette. Because the error messages are displayed with the red background.
